# how to remove a html tag from the parent in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<td>
    <input type='checkbox' value='-1' name='xxx' checked>XXX
    <input type='hidden' value='-1' name='xxx'>
</td>
<td>
    <input type='checkbox' value='-1' name='xyy' checked>Xyy
    <input type='hidden' value='-1' name='xyy'>
</td>
<td>
    <input type='checkbox' value='-1' name='yyy' checked>yyy
    <input type='hidden' value='-1' name='yyy'>
</td>
```

In the above code I set a hidden value with same name as on submition of form neither 0 nor 1 is being submitted. Now I got a problem that when I click the checkbox I want to remove the `input:hidden` node and remain will same. But using `$("input:hidden").remove()` its removing the total hidden values present in the document.

Comment: Can you reframe your question into what you want and what is happening? It is not very clear right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this if you have that html structure. It simply removes next hidden input of checked checkbox.

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
  $(this).next("input:hidden").remove();
});
```

If you want to delete them only when checkbox is checked you can add this condition

```
if ($(this).is (':checked'))
```

Comment: cant i use input hidden tag inside the remove() method as i am getting  the total content using parent()

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you explain it in more details?

Comment: It's really hillarious that you changed accepted answer from mine to the answer that is the same and is posted 1 hour later xD

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name=xxx]:hidden").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() { 
$(this).next("input:hidden").remove(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
    <input type='checkbox' value='-1' name='xyy' class='xyz' checked>Xyy
    <input type='hidden' value='-1' name='xyy'  class='xyz'>
</td>.

$("input.xyy:hidden").remove();
```

Added a class and managed the requirenment.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is needlessly complicated if you ask me. An `<input type='checkbox' value='-1' name='xxx' checked/>` returns the `value` to the backend if it is checked else it returns nothing. So essentially it does the same thing you are trying to accomplish by putting those extra hidden fields and removing them - a lot more efficiently, I might add.

Please do review the code you have written. You may refer [here](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html) for knowing how checkboxes are handled.

Comment: hey, I completed this project successfully 7months ago . its for tri-state check-box where the view will be like gmail's inbox feature. In gmail it uses all check-box as images i used one half-checked image and the original check-box for full check and unchecked.

But Thanks for your commentry..